# MVC executing a LibreOffice conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, batch-file, libreoffice

Hi I'm trying to convert either a doc or docx to a pdf in a c# MVC application. I know I can do this using libreOffice. So I created a simple batch file to take 2 variables and then run them into the libreoffice 'soffice' headless to convert to pdf.

So that gave me this code.

```
echo on

SET var1=%2

IF "%var1:~-1%"=="\" SET var1=%var1:~0,-1%

cd "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\"

soffice --headless --convert-to pdf %1 --outdir %var1%
```

Originally I thought the problem was within my MVC application and the way I called this batch script. But I commented (REM) the soffice and outputted out the command in the bash using the standard output.

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/k " + command);
              //psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
                psi.FileName = command;
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                psi.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", fullPath2, tempPath);

                var process = Process.Start(psi);

                string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();


                Trace.WriteLine(output);
                Trace.WriteLine(error);

                process.WaitForExit();
```

When I commented the soffice line  - it hit the WaitForExit and worked no problems (ok with no pdf conversions, but the script exited).

If I don't do that it seems to execute the cmd and even the soffice commands because I can see them in the task manager - but obvisouly nothing happens.

Additionally the code above works when I did a c# command line program (I've hard coded the file/command lines in both instances). The executable also works when I run as the user that is running the app pool in my MVC application.

The bash file also works file 'standalone' no matter if me or my appPool user run it.

So what gives - why won't this run.

This is the code that comes out of that trace - so what the bash script does.

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>echo on 

c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>SET var1=C:\inetpub\xxxxxxxxx\Temp\ 

c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>IF "\" == "\" SET var1=C:\inetpub\xxxxxxxxx\Temp 

c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>cd "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\" 

C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program>soffice --headless --convert-to pdf C:\inetpub\xxxxxxxxx\Temp\636295920370843147.doc --outdir C:\inetpub\xxxxxxxxx\Temp
```

I've got a feeling that this has something to do with the amount of characters or something because the soffice does fireup (can see it in the task manager).

FYI there are no spaces or special characters anywhere.

Any ideas?

Update
This looks to be an issue with the wait command. So any help with that helpful, I'm starting to think perhaps this is an issue with c# and libreoffice 5 - I've seen examples that supposedly work with libreoffice 4.
I guess my challenge continues....

Comment: Thy to enclose your files in quotes in the line with soffice. Try also to use full path of soffice command: `"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice"` - also in quotes.

Comment: Tried those things

Comment: Just a quick note did a whoami > test.txt in the bash and got the expected app pool user